# Trying to echo/redirect/append a variable value that has & and spaces in it without the quotes messing things up

Tags: batch-file, echo, quotes, io-redirection, ampersand

In a batch file, suppose %PageName% has the value:

```
This & That
```

And %FolderName%:

```
Stuff & Junk
```

I want to be able to echo the following line and append it to an HTML file.  The expanded or "rendered" form of the line would look like this inside of the HTML file:

```
<li> <a href="Stuff & Junk/This & That.html">This & That</a></li>
```

And of course in a perfect world, I could just type this in the batch file to produce this result:

```
echo <li> <a href="Stuff & Junk/This & That.html">This & That</a></li> >> "Stuff & Junk/index.html"
```

But of course this isn't a perfect world, and having ampersands and spaces stored inside variables makes everything a billion times more of a headache.  I tried:

```
echo ^<li^> ^<a href="%FolderName%"/"%PageName%".html^>"%PageName%"^</a^>^</li^> >> "%FolderName%\index.html"
```

This appends the following text to the index.html file:

```
<li> <a href="Stuff & Junk"/"This & That".html>"This & That"</a></li>
```

...which is awful because the quotation marks screw up everything.  But if I get rid of the quotes, I get syntax errors because of the ampersands that break the line up into multiple commands.  I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What about this: `(echo ^<li^>^<a href="%FolderName%/%PageName%.html"^>%PageName:&=^&%^</a^>^</li^>) >> "%FolderName%/index.html"`?

Comment: Wow that works too... quite creative - I had no idea one could put a command in parentheses without using an "if" statement!

Comment: Well, the parentheses are just there to avoid a trailing space at the end of the output line. The trick here is to escape the ampersand only when it appears unquoted, which is where it would harm…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "pagename=This & That"
SET "foldername=Stuff & Junk"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ("%pagename%") DO FOR /f "delims=" %%y IN ("%foldername%") DO ECHO ^<li^> ^<a href="%%y%%e.html"^>%%y^</a^>^</li^>

GOTO :EOF
```

The trick is to assign the awkward string to a metavariable (`%%e/%%y`) and `echo` the result before `cmd` has a chance to figure out what's going on...

Comment: Holy Gosh Heavens to Betsy Almighty Moly Guacamole!  That is the only phrase I could think of that was appropriate for your solution... using nested 1-item for loops to make CMD do something it doesn't want to do.  I must admit I feel way better knowing that this was essentially impossible for all people with IQs less than 7,590.  Thank you and roo times two, Magoo!  (roo because you're in Australia...)